# publicly available spam dataset of social networks

Tags: data-request, network-structure, machine-learning, social-media

I am trying to create a naive bayes spam filter for social networks and i need a spam dataset (containing posts/tweets etc.) of popular social networks like twitter/facebook. Is there any publicly available dataset which i can use to train the classifier?

Answer (score 6):

From the [Machine Learning Repository at UCI](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html) there are some datasets that may get you started.

- [emails](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Spambase)
- [SMS](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/SMS+Spam+Collection)

For emails you may also find this [StackOverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4743996/2327328) helpful, or this 3[00+MB dataset](http://plg.uwaterloo.ca/~gvcormac/treccorpus/).

For blogs marked as spam, check out [this site](http://ebiquity.umbc.edu/resource/html/id/212/Splog-Blog-Dataset).

Twitter data are not allowed to be publically shared. You can share the analysis or the visualization, but not the raw data of tweets. I imagine Facebook has a similar policy.

But, you can collect more than you ever dreamed of by using the [public live stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public). Here is an [example python code](https://github.com/uwescience/datasci_course_materials/blob/master/assignment1/twitterstream.py) to collect many, many tweets as they are sent. There should be plenty of spam if you let it run for a couple minutes.

Answer (score 1):

More than a decade ago, when I worked for an ISP, I subscribed to the [spamtools](http://www.abuse.net/spamtools.html) mailing list.  Unfortunately, their archives link doesn't work, so I have no idea if they're still active or not.

They also were more focused on e-mail spam, but at the time social network spam didn't really exist (as social networks didn't really exist in the state they do today).

I would suspect that if someone had a training set, it'd be someone on that list.  I'd also assume that twitter spam would be significantly different from blog or e-mail spam, due to the character limitations.